# How to get the value inside a specific table cell using XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, behat, acceptance-testing, gherkin

I'm learning how to use Behat/Mink and Selenium to write acceptance tests, and I need to verify the value of a specific table cell. I found that I have to use xpath to do this, but I can't figure out the exact syntax. The table is as follows:

[image]

The html:

```
<table class="admintable generaltable" id="relationships">
<thead>
...
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody><tr class="r0 lastrow">
<td class="leftalign cell c0" style="">Cohort 1</td>
<td class="leftalign cell c1" style="">0</td>
<td class="leftalign cell c2" style="">Non-editing teacher</td>
<td class="centeralign cell c3" style="">No</td>
<td class="leftalign cell c4" style="">No</td>
<td class="leftalign cell c5 lastcol" style=""><a href="http://150.162.242.121/mariana/unasus-cp/local/relationship/edit_cohort.php?relationshipcohortid=1&amp;delete=1"><img src="http://150.162.242.121/mariana/unasus-cp/theme/image.php/standard/core/1445875205/t/delete" alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="iconsmall" /></a> <a href="http://150.162.242.121/mariana/unasus-cp/local/relationship/edit_cohort.php?relationshipcohortid=1"><img src="http://150.162.242.121/mariana/unasus-cp/theme/image.php/standard/core/1445875205/t/edit" alt="Edit" title="Edit" class="iconsmall" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The statement I'm trying to write is:

```
Then I should see "No" in the "???" "css_element"
```

How exactly should I write that statement to specify that I want that first "No", under "Inscrição em vários grupos", in the "No" part.

EDIT: I made a mistake originally, I should be using "xpath_element" as a selector, not "css_element"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the `Inscrição em vários grupos` text always appears in the 4th column. Writing XPath for this is pretty easy as we can directly use the index.

```
//table[@id='relationships']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]
```

If the column number of the heading column varies you would have to find the index(column number) of the `Inscrição em vários grupos` heading and then use it to find the corresponding value column.

```
-- the below code will get you the index of the heading column
count(//thead//tr/th[.='Inscrição em vários grupo']/preceding-sibling::*)+1

-- use this index to find the corresponding value
//table[@id='relationships']/tbody/tr[1]/td[count(//thead//tr/th[.='Inscrição em vários grupo']/preceding-sibling::*)+1]
```

**Note: Index starts from 1 not 0**

From the following link, syntax in behat seems to be as follows:

[How to assert that a text only exists 1 time in Mink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19161375/how-to-assert-that-a-text-only-exists-1-time-in-mink)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32202047/could-not-find-element-with-xpath-in-behat-mink

```
$session = $this->getMainContext()->getSession();
$element = $session->getPage()->find(
        'xpath',
        $session->getSelectorsHandler()->selectorToXpath('xpath', '//table[@id='relationships']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]');
$elementText = $element->getText();

if ($elementText != 'no') {
    throw new Exception('Value us not correct');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding! The xpath you suggested returned an error (Css matching locator "//table[@id='relationships']/tbody//td[3]" not found.) The position doesnt vary, so I don't understand why this locator doesnt work

Comment: It still doesn't seem to work. The step I'm writing is "Then I should see "No" in the "//table[@id='relationships']/tbody//tr[4]" "css_element"", is that correct?

Comment: Please check my answer. The xpath is `//table[@id='relationships']/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]`. What is this "css_element"?

Comment: It's part of the Behat step

Comment: My bad, I should be using "xpath_element"! Your original suggestion for the xpath worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but did you try a simple CSS selector like `td.c3`? It seems a lot more straightforward to me.

Comment: I don't remember, but I think I tried it and for some reason it wasn't working via css selector. Maybe there were other td with c3 as a class